Upgrade to 24.04 (+nvidia), system only boots in nomodeset
I checked all the previous posts, but the thing doesn't boot if I don't set "nomodeset".
I tried:

removing ALL nvidia drivers and installing 535
removing ALL nvidia drivers and installing 550
trying nouveau

Nothing helps - it only works when I add "nomodeset" to the boot process. Before the update, I was using dont-know-which NVIDIA drivers version and it always worked OK.
If I do "nosplash", I can see the boot process (it mounts the root partition, systemd starts SOME services,..) but then it comes to a black screen (tries to initialize GPU) and the computer completely freezes (CTRL+ALT+Fx, ALT+Fx don't work, nor does CAPS LOCK turn on the LED). The stupid thing is, there is NOTHING in the  boot log or syslog, like those boots never happened! Bootlog entries for those boots are not there.
Some info: kde neon upgraded to ubuntu 24.04 LTS, nvidia 1060.
Logs: nothing inthere.
Kernel: Linux FDV 6.8.0-49-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Nov  4 02:06:24 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
AND 6.8.0-48-generic.
Any ideas? :-/

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=260695
This worked for me
Just add nosplash to grub boot options and u won't need to enter this option every time
Registered only 2 help u xd

UPD: My friend has some ASUS motherboard that wouldn't let me disable secure boot at all. On top of that, it somehow kept reverting the boot mode back to "Windows UEFI" or something like that (there's a second option "Other OS").
So, the next day the drivers crashed, and I had to start all over again. Here are the steps I took to finally solve it:

In the motherboard settings, I set it to use only the graphics card, without the integrated graphics.
I booted into Kubuntu (which started with the integrated graphics again), pressed Ctrl+Alt+F1 and Ctrl+Alt+F6 to access the console and reinstall the drivers.
I removed old proprietary driver installed from the Nvidia website (not sure why I did this, I was just trying everything xd).
I installed the new driver using sudo apt-get install nvidia*560*.
During the installation process, the driver generated a new Machine Owner Key since it detected that the system was booting in secure boot

Probably your motherboard won't be as messed up and will let you simply disable secure boot.
After rebooting the PC, everything worked, no idea how, but it worked.
Moreover, I messed up editing the GRUB boot commands, and now I have nomodeset quiet splash there, but even so, Kubuntu starts with the GPU, and everything is fine.
If u still have any troubles, u can mail me (onaovee@gmail.com), I'll be glad to help)
